# Snowflake stuttering Worksheet

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

so I have this issue, that everytime snowflake is trying to save the worksheet I get a lag for almost 4 seconds and this happens a lot once you start writing code.

Does anyone have any idea how this happens?

I cleaned the cash and deleted google chrome and installed it again.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: How big is the SQL in the worksheet (# lines of code)? Do you have many other worksheets open at the same time?

Comment: That can be challenging to narrow down.  If you have a lot of worksheets or SQL in general, that may contribute. Try a new user who will start with only one worksheet and see if the issue is the same. It could also be a networking delay so testing on other networks or machines is good. Using Incognito Mode on Chrome is another good test as it will also ensure no extensions are causing a delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Snowflake worksheet feels delayed, it might be because you have too many worksheets archived. When you click the `x` button next to a worksheet, this does not delete that sheet. To fully delete your worksheets, click the down arrow to the right of the + sign next to your newest sheet. Click on `open worksheet`, and it will show you all of your existing sheets. You can delete them using the trash can button on the top right.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 4sec is normal. Snowflake highlighted "All changes to individual worksheets are auto-saved quickly in the background"..

Comment: no no 1


If your Snowflake worksheet feels delayed, it might be because you have too many worksheets archived. When you click the x button next to a worksheet, this does not delete that sheet. To fully delete your worksheets, click the down arrow to the right of the + sign next to your newest sheet. Click on open worksheet, and it will show you all of your existing sheets. You can delete them using the trash can button on the top right.